# Transposing string and counting frequencies for multilabel dataset

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

Have a pandas dataframe with 2 columns: `tag` and `message`:

```
       tag              |     message
["string1","sttring2"]  |    some text
["string","string3"]    |  another text
["string2"]             | another another text
```

I am running this code to extract the strings in the `df['tag']` column:

```
strings_list = set(df['text'].str.extractall('\"([^"]+)\"')[0])
```

And I get a list of distinct string: `string1`, `string2`,`string3`, `string`

And I am also running this code to count the frequencies of each string in the `tag` column:

```
import ast
df.tag.map(ast.literal_eval).explode().value_counts()
```

The dataframe has 40 distinct `strings` in the `tag` column.

**What I need:**

I need to transpose this list of 40 distinct tag and then insert the count of each relative to the message column.  This will be a multi-label dataset.

So the final dataframe should be like this:

```
      tag              |     message           string  string1   string2    string3
["string1","sttring2"]  |    some text            0      1          1          0        
["string","string3"]    |  another text           1      0          0          3
["string2"]             | another another text    0      0          1          0
```

I already know how to count the frequencies and how to extract the string but I am having a hard to time to accomplish this last task.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to first `explode()` the tag column in order to separate the list into individual rows. Then use `pivot()` to get a column for each of your tags. Then setting null values to zero and the not null values to one. In the end, merge with your original dataframe to get the correct format. Here is the code:

```
frequency_df = df.explode('tag').pivot(columns='tag', index='message', values='message').notnull().astype(int)
df = df.merge(frequency_df, on='message')

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                  tag               message  string  string1  string2  string3
0  [string1, string2]             some text       0        1        1        0
1   [string, string3]          another text       1        0        0        1
2           [string2]  another another text       0        0        1        0
```

Comment: It's not spliting the lines with more than 1 string Jano. I tried to change it a bit too but no success so far. Thx

Comment: So, do you mean that row `2` works and `0` and `1` do not work? Or is some different input with different lines not working? Can you tell me what input causes the wrong output?